# How to Distribute iOS Enterprise App through Apple Mobile Device Managment(MDM)

Tags: ios, mdm, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

I am trying to check if the Enterprise iOS Application can be distributed through Apple MDM. I read through [Distributing Enterprise Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW6) where it says "Distribute the iOS App file using MDM".

I also read some of this document of [MDM](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Enterprise_Deployment_Overview.pdf) but its too messy. Can someone list some simple steps to distribute Enterprise Apps through MDM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which MDM solution do you use?

Comment: I have been using hockeyapp in the past but I want to know if there is any good

Comment: How many devices do you have?